# How to call object initialized to a number?

Tags: python, class, variables, methods, numbers

If I were to have these functions in a class, how would I call them from another function in the same class?

```
class Dead:
    def initial(self):
        self.amy = 1
        self.bob = 2
        self.cam = 3

    def __init__(self):
        self.initial()

    def get_number(self, number):
```

How could I call self.amy, and in return be getting the number 1? In get_number I would like to add like self.amy to a number to return the sum, but like with all amy, bob, cam in one go with a for function maybe? I'm not sure how to word this question without completely spoiling the question, sorry.

Comment: Why do you even need `get_number`? just do `self.amy` from other methods in the class

Comment: @DeepSpace idk that's just the way my teacher gave the problem to us

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `get_number` method to accept a member variable name instead and dynamically retrieve it. E.g.

```
class Dead:
    def initial(self):
        self.amy = 1
        self.bob = 2
        self.cam = 3

    def __init__(self):
        self.initial()

    def get_number(self, name, number):
        return getattr(self, name) + number
```

However, this is more than redundant. You can already access those variables from your object, adding a method to access them is adding an extra layer for no reason.

```
class Dead:
    def initial(self):
        self.amy = 1
        self.bob = 2
        self.cam = 3

    def __init__(self):
        self.initial()

dead = Dead()
dead.amy # 1
dead.bob # 2
dead.cam # 3
dead.amy += 1 # 2
```

So is adding an `initial` method to initialize your member variables. No reason not to do so inside your `__init__` directly.

```
class Dead:
    def __init__(self):
        self.amy = 1
        self.bob = 2
        self.cam = 3
```

Adding useless methods is not making your code better, it really just pollute it.